# Iphone Call Accessors / Properties in initializers

Tags: iphone

Why is a bad idea to call:

```
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user",nil];
```

in the initializers if the dataArray is set as a property?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to remember.. nothing to do with properties

```
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user",nil];
```

is equivalent to

```
[self setDataArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user",nil]];
```

so you are calling the accessor -setDataArray:

Now, lets say *CollegueA* subclasses this class as *ClassB* and overides -setDataArray:

CollegueA has every right to expect that for an instance of ClassB her -init has been called and that the instance will have finished initailzion before -setDataArray: is called. ie. that in her setDataArray: method self is properly initialised. This is not what will happen with your example code. Her -setDataArray: will be called from your -init method before her -init has even been run.

In a project where you are the sole developer, assuming you are not writing a framework intended to be shared, i say not a major worry. But then i would still prefer

```
dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user",nil];
```